# hide the mutual edges from sigma js nodes

Tags: jquery, nodes, edges, sigma.js

I am trying to hide the edges which are showing interrelation between child nodes means connecting child nodes each other.

I tried this function sigInst.dropEdge(e.id) but it completely remove the edges.

Answer (score 0):

```html
//****Remove the connection edges between child nodes

//check between outgoing node relation
        $.each(outgoing, function(node ) {
            $.each(outgoing, function(node1 ) {
            sigInst.iterEdges(function(e) {
              if ( ((e.source == node) && (e.target == node1)) || ((e.source == node1) && (e.target == node))) {
                //sigInst.dropEdge(e.id);
                e.hidden = true;
                console.log("edge dropped");
              }
                });
                sigInst.refresh();
        });
});

//check between incoming node relation
        $.each(incoming, function(node ) {
            $.each(incoming, function(node1 ) {
            sigInst.iterEdges(function(e) {
              if ( ((e.source == node) && (e.target == node1)) || ((e.source == node1) && (e.target == node))) {
                //sigInst.dropEdge(e.id);
                e.hidden = true;
                console.log("edge dropped");
              }
                });
                sigInst.refresh();
        });
});

//check between outgoing and incoming node relation
        $.each(outgoing, function(node ) {
            $.each(incoming, function(node1 ) {
            sigInst.iterEdges(function(e) {
              if ( ((e.source == node) && (e.target == node1)) || ((e.source == node1) && (e.target == node))) {
                //sigInst.dropEdge(e.id);
                e.hidden = true;
                console.log("edge dropped");
              }
                });
        });
});
  sigInst.draw();
```